# Is there any way to insert action buttons in notification in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I need to add a notification in the chrome with 2 buttons 'allow' and 'deny'.When the user clicks on 'allow' button, it has to navigate to a website and when the user clicks on 'deny' the notification box shouldn't appear anymore.That is it have to close.How can I do it?Please help me
THis is my background.js

```
        function getGmailUrl() {
      return "http://calpinemate.com/";
      }
        function isGmailUrl(url) {

      return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
    }
      chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

 chrome.tabs.query({
    url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
    currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
        console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         updateIcon();
    } else {
        console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
         updateIcon();
       }
      });
    });



    function updateIcon(){

      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
       if (req.readyState == 4) {
       if (req.status == 200) {
        localStorage.item=req.responseText;
        //alert(localStorage.item);
        if(localStorage.item==1){
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   
        }
        else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
        }

      } else {
        // Handle the error
        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
      }
    }
    });
       req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
   req.send(null);
       }

       var myNotificationID = null;

           /* For demonstration purposes, the notification creation 
      * is attached to the browser-action's `onClicked` event.
      * Change according to your needs. */
          chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
             chrome.notifications.create("", {
    type:    "basic",
    iconUrl: "http://calpinemate.com/icon_128.png",
    title:   "REMINDER",
    message: "It's time to go to this super-cool site !\nProceed ?",
    contextMessage: "It's about time...",
    buttons: [{
        title: "Yes, get me there",

    }, {
        title: "Get out of my way",

    }]
      }, function(id) {
    myNotificationID = id;
    });
    });

  /* Respond to the user's clicking one of the buttons */
    chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
      if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
      if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("...");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
        saySorry();
    }
    }
 });

    /* Add this to also handle the user's clicking 
      * the small 'x' on the top right corner */
     chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
     saySorry();
       });

        /* Handle the user's rejection 
    * (simple ignore if you just want to hide the notification) */
         function saySorry() {
      alert("Sorry to bother you !");
      }
```

Edited background.js

```
  var myNotificationID = null;
  var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;

   function getGmailUrl() {
     return "http://calpinemate.com/";
     }
    function isGmailUrl(url) {

    return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
       }

   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.query({
    url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
    currentWindow: true
   }, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
        console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         updateIcon();
    } else {
        console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
         updateIcon();
    }
    });


});
    function onInit() {
   console.log('onInit');
      updateIcon();
   if (!oldChromeVersion) {
    chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});
  }
 }

   function onAlarm(alarm) {
  console.log('Got alarm', alarm);
    if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
      onWatchdog();
       } else {
   updateIcon();
   }
    }

    function onWatchdog() {
     chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
       if (alarm) {
        console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');
         } else {
       console.log('Refresh alarm doesn\'t exist!? ' +
              'Refreshing now and rescheduling.');
        updateIcon();
       }
       });
      }
     if (oldChromeVersion) {
    updateIcon();
    onInit();
  } else {
     chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
       chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
         }

  function updateIcon(){

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
     if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {

        var item=req.responseText;

        if(item==1){
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   
        }
        else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
        }

    } else {

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);
    }
    }
  }); 
    req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
     req.send(null);
       }
    var notification=chrome.notifications.create("", {
    type:    "basic",
    iconUrl: "/path/to/notification/icon.png",
    title:   "REMINDER",
    message: "It's time to go to this super-cool site !\nProceed ?",
    contextMessage: "It's about time...",
    buttons: [{
        title: "Yes, get me there",
        iconUrl: "/path/to/yesIcon.png"
    }, {
        title: "Get out of my way",
        iconUrl: "/path/to/noIcon.png"
    }]
   }, function(id) {
    myNotificationID = id;
});
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
        saySorry();
    }
     }
   });

   chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
saySorry();
 });

    function saySorry() {
    alert("Sorry to bother you !");
     }
   notification.show();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Everything you'll need is provided by the **[chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications)**. E.g.:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [
            "./bg/background.js"
        ]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
    },

    "permissions": ["notifications"]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
var myNotificationID = null;

/* For demonstration purposes, the notification creation 
 * is attached to the browser-action's `onClicked` event.
 * Change according to your needs. */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.notifications.create("", {
        type:    "basic",
        iconUrl: "/path/to/notification/icon.png",
        title:   "REMINDER",
        message: "It's time to go to this super-cool site !\nProceed ?",
        contextMessage: "It's about time...",
        buttons: [{
            title: "Yes, get me there",
            iconUrl: "/path/to/yesIcon.png"
        }, {
            title: "Get out of my way",
            iconUrl: "/path/to/noIcon.png"
        }]
    }, function(id) {
        myNotificationID = id;
    });
});

/* Respond to the user's clicking one of the buttons */
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
    if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
        if (btnIdx === 0) {
            window.open("...");
        } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
            saySorry();
        }
    }
});

/* Add this to also handle the user's clicking 
 * the small 'x' on the top right corner */
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
    saySorry();
});

/* Handle the user's rejection 
 * (simple ignore if you just want to hide the notification) */
function saySorry() {
    alert("Sorry to bother you !");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I would check it

Comment: I just realized, it's you (again). So, what is not working ? The exact same code works fine for me. Do you get any errors ?

Comment: BTW, since you seem to have a lot of questions, I thought I'd just let you know it is customary to also upvote the accepted answer (or any other answer that you find useful or worth noting).

Comment: Sure i would upvote when i accept the answer.But I am not getting the apt answer

Comment: should i change this?  "/path/to/yesIcon.png"  what should i put in place of this?

Comment: Yes, you should change the icon-paths to point to an image that is displayed in the notification. (You can delete the buttons' `iconUrl`s, since they are optional, but the first one is mandatory.)

Comment: and what about window .open??what should come in place of window.open(..)??

Comment: "_Due to a strict Content Security Policy in Chrome Apps, these URLs must point to a local resource or use a data URL._". This means cannot an iconUrl pointing to `http://...`, but you need to have it bundled with your extension. To open a page, do: `window.open("http://www.google.com")` (replace the URL woth the site you want to open).

Comment: SO What you are trying to convey?what I have to change?

Comment: Replace: `iconUrl: "http://calpinemate.com/icon_128.png",` with `iconUrl: "/icon_128.png",` (after you save the image in your extension's root directory). Replace `window.open(...);` with `window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");`

Comment: the above code is my background.js file.I don't know whether there is any mistake

Comment: Is it because there is two onclick functions written??

Comment: What `onclick` ? I don't see any `onclick`.

Comment: chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) ..this is what i said..all the actions are performed when clicking on the extension icon.I want it to be done on startup of the chrome extension.Please help me

Comment: I saw you figured it out yourself. If you want something to happen when the extension is installed, please do not say you want it to happen when the extension start's up, because it is something completely different. Use `osStartup` for when it start's up, use `onInstalled` for when it is installed. Also, accept the answer if it solves your original problem which was about notifications.

Comment: no the notification problem is not working.it is not even showing the notification box.But I have come up with a small code.But I don't know how to add buttons in the notification box.Please help me.I have posted another question.Please have a look on it

Comment: The notification is definitely working, because I copied and pasted from my working extension. Posting multiple questions in the same subject and not accepting or upvoting the working solutions given to you is not going to help you solve the problems. I am sorry.

Comment: How about...debugging !

Comment: hii ihave updated my question.please have a look at edited background.js

Comment: Hi I tried your code in a separate directory.but then also it is not working.Can you give the link that showed the notification in js fiddle? please help me..

Comment: Download this ZIP archive: **[`https://db.tt/DGt6U9u8`](https://db.tt/DGt6U9u8)** Then Unpack it and load it as an unpacked extension (in developer mode). Finally, click on the browser action button to see the notification.

Comment: I tried it from 3 different PCs and it is downloading fine. It is a Dropbox shortened URL, so I doubt there are going to be any server errors.

Comment: It is because some sites are blocked in this system.Is there any other way to download it?

Comment: Hi now your code is working.But other than button everything else is shown,including the notification message.only the button is not being shown.Is there any permission needed to display button?

Comment: @user1991: Hm, what is your Chrome version ? (BTW, if you believe an answer is helpful, consider upvoting it as well.)

Comment: Version 30.0.1599.114...this is my google chrome version.And i have accepted your answer.

Comment: Dude, relax ! We have exchanged over 100 coments in the past days - I **am** trying to help you. So: I doubt this is the problem, but just in case, could upgrade to the latest Chrome version ? Are you sure you are not seeing the buttons (they don't actually look like buttons - they look like two plain divs, stacked obe under the other). You'll recognise them by the button-texts.

Comment: OK, is it possible toupgrade tothe latest versionof Chrome ?

Comment: Hi I updated my version to' Version 31.0.1650.57'.But now also the button is not being shown.Please help me.I am not able to figure out what is the problem.Please help me..

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Web Notifications API's Notification object. This will create a notification every 10 seconds, that when clicked on will open a new window, but can be closed with no effect.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Notification Demo",
  "version": "0",
  "description":
    "Proof of concept - Web Notifications API",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
function show() {
    notification = new Notification("Test", {
       body: 'click the notification to open example.com, or click to the x to close'
    });
    notification.onclick = function(){
        window.open('http://example.com');
        window.focus();
    };
};

show();

var interval = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    interval++;
    show();
    interval = 0;
}, 10000);
```

Here's a Chrome notifications demo that I've found helpful:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/notifications.zip

You can learn more about the Notification object:

http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-web-notifications-api/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications

Comment: -1. This is a "link-only answer", and besides your choice of API will not fulfill the requirements in the question.

Comment: My -1 stays: the question calls for, I quote, _"a notification in the chrome with 2 buttons 'allow' and 'deny'"_. Your solution does not provide it (cannot provide it), unlike the other existing solution using `chrome.notifications` API. As such, it's not useful.

Comment: FWIW, the two clickable options are "allow" and "deny" functionally and intuitively, if not explicitly. Moreover, like the OP, I couldn't get the current solution to work either, so I'm offering one that works cut-and-paste style.