# How to insert notification action buttons in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Hi I am in need to develop a notification with 2 buttons performing different actions.One button is 'MARK' and other one is 'IGNORE'.When I click MARK button it has to navigate to a website.And when I click IGNORE,the notification box should be invisible and should not be shown anymore.How can I do that? 
Here is my background.js

```
  var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;

  function getGmailUrl() {
    return "http://calpinemate.com/";
    }
       function isGmailUrl(url) {

       return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
      }

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

     chrome.tabs.query({
    url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",
    currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);
        console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
         updateIcon();
    } else {
        console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });
         updateIcon();
    }
     });
     });
   function onInit() {
      console.log('onInit');
      updateIcon();
      if (!oldChromeVersion) {
      chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});
         }
          }

        function onAlarm(alarm) {
       console.log('Got alarm', alarm);
     if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
    onWatchdog();
   } else {
    updateIcon();
       }
     }

     function onWatchdog() {
      chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
        if (alarm) {
     console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');
    } else {
   console.log('Refresh alarm doesn\'t exist!? ' +
              'Refreshing now and rescheduling.');
    updateIcon();
   }
  });
 }
    if (oldChromeVersion) {
   updateIcon();
   onInit();
    } else {
        chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
        chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
       }

       function updateIcon(){

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
  }
 });
 req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);
 req.send(null);
  }

 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
 '/icon_128.png',  // icon url - can be relative
'Hello!',  // notification title
'Lorem ipsum...'  // notification body text
 );

 notification.show();
```

Comment: _"Possible"_ duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188792/how-to-add-a-notification-in-google-chrome-with-2-buttons/.

Comment: But it didn't solve my problem.please help me

Comment: In my above code,it shows notification,but I don't know how to insert buttons into the notification box.please help me.

Comment: Using the chrome.notifications API described in the answer of the other question is they way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>For anyone landing on this page looking for a way to add buttons to notifications or trying to figure out why no buttons are shown:</sub>

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188792/is-there-any-way-way-to-insert-action-buttons-in-notification-inside-google-chro#answer-20190702)** explains in detail how to create notifications and how to add buttons.

---

Nonetheless, the buttons are not displayed on some distributions of Linux.
This is **[a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310799)** (still holding for Chrome version 31.0.1650.57) and *is dependent on `Views` shipping on Linux*.

**EDIT:** According to **[this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=291485)**, buttons work on Linux as well (at least since Chrome 35).

Comment: Hey can you please check this link?I have been trying this for three days.But not getting any idea.please help me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374013/how-to-perform-chrome-run-onstartup-in-chrome-extension-in-linux

Comment: Relax ! I have it in my todo list. I will take a look into it as soon as possible. Positing the same question multiple times won't help. (And adding a "Please, help me" comment every 5 minutes is very likely to irritate people and have the opposite effect.) I'll get back to you as soon as I get a chance to take a look, don't worry !

Comment: When asking questions, you might want to trim the code you share to the minimum necessary. The chunk after `var req = new XMLHttpRequest();` isn't relevant for the question.

Comment: @ExpertSystem i used yr code  if (btnIdx === 0) { window.open("...");} it was working before (since last 3 month) but i dont know what went wrong now it's not working when i click on notification button[Go to Mysite]  obviously it do redirect me to my website e.g www.mysite.com but then later it gives me aw..snap page error and site stop loading. do i have to declare anything in manifest file ? in chrome 49 it's not working but in chrome 50 it'works fine . can you suggest me what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you're building a Chrome extension, you have access to a special notifications API, which doesn't need to bug the user for permission to show Desktop notifications - [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

To add the buttons to the notification window, you don't need to write any HTML code. Just write this:

```
chrome.notifications.create('yourNotificationName', {
  type: 'basic',
  iconUrl: '...',
  title: 'Calpine something',
  message: 'This is the message displayed by the notification',
  buttons: [
    { title: 'Mark' },
    { title: 'Ignore' }
  ]
}, function callback(notificationId) {
  // nothing necessary here, but required before Chrome 42
});
```