# Notification action button is not shown in the notification box

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

can anyone please give the syntax for chrome notification containing buttons??I am not sure about the syntax for adding buttons to notification box in chrome.Can anyone please help me??
This is my code for notification.

```
  chrome.notifications.create(
    'id1',{   
     type: 'basic',
     iconUrl: '/icon_128.png',
     title: 'Althe Frazon',
     message: 'Lorem ipsum',
     buttons: [{ title: 'Call'
             },
           { title: 'Send Email'
             }],
     priority: 0
      },
     function() { /* Error checking goes here */}
      ); 
 notification.show();
```

Using this code the notification is shown.But the buttons are not shown.Anygone please guess the reason.Why my buttons are not shown??Please help me

Comment: **[`chrome.notifications.create`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#method-create)** _creates and displays_ a notification, so there is no need for `notification.show()`. (What does it refer to anyway ?)

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: [chrome.notifications.create does not display the Buttons](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310799)

Comment: @user1991: Hm...it seems to be an OS-dependent issue. What OS are you on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>For anyone landing on this page looking for a way to add buttons to notifications or trying to figure out why no buttons are shown:</sub>

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188792/is-there-any-way-way-to-insert-action-buttons-in-notification-inside-google-chro#answer-20190702)** explains in detail how to create notifications and how to add buttons.

Nonetheless, the buttons are not displayed on some distributions of Linux.
This is **[a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310799)** (still holding for Chrome version 31.0.1650.57) and *is dependent on `Views` shipping on Linux*.