# Can I include more than 2 action buttons in chrome notification?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

if I include 3 buttons in chrome desktop notification, it is displaying only two buttons, is there a way I can add more than two action buttons ? if not can i implement action list items ? if so kindly let me know.

For your reference : [Is there any way to insert action buttons in notification in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188792/is-there-any-way-to-insert-action-buttons-in-notification-in-google-chrome/26108713#26108713)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#type-NotificationOptions) on `buttons` property:

> Text and icons for **up to two** notification action buttons.

Hence, it seems that having more than 2 buttons display is not possible with chrome API.

You could use [onClosed](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#event-onClosed) and [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#event-onClicked) for more control.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for now supports only 2 action buttons.

> "Currently Chrome only supports two actions on each notification. Some
>   platforms might be able to support more, and some platforms may
>   support less or none at all. You can determine what the platform
>   supports by checking Notification.maxActions."

Refer here for more info: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/notification-actions?hl=en