# actions for chrome notification not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

Hello I am trying to create a chrome notification and I want to add actions onto the notification so the user can select the options. I have tried to run this code but it doesnt work for some reason:

```
var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Restock",
    message: "Tee Black",
    iconUrl: '/images/Hp_Beta7.png',
    actions: [
        {title: "small", action: "action1"},
        {title: "medium", action: "action2"}
        ]
};

chrome.notifications.create(options, callback);

function callback() {
    console.log("popup done");
}
```

the notification works fine without the actions part but I want to be able to have a select in the notification and every time I try and run this script I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

that points to the "actions: [" line

is there something That I am missing?

Any help is apreciated. Thank You <3 !

Comment: Missing a comma before the actions key.

Comment: @wOxxOm I fixed that then I got this error.. Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'actions': Unexpected property.

Comment: There is no `actions` key for notifications. Use `buttons`, like `"buttons":[{"title":"action1","iconUrl":"button1.png"}]`. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Answer (score 1):

The property "`actions`" does not exist for notifications. "`buttons`" is used to add action buttons in the notification.

Also, in "`chrome.notifications.create(options, callback);`", the parameter list is not correct since the first parameter is "`notificationId`" which is set to `""` in case not used.

Here is an answer which explains well how to use the buttons in chrome notification- [Is there any way to insert action buttons in notification in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188792/is-there-any-way-to-insert-action-buttons-in-notification-in-google-chrome#answer-20190702)

**background.js**

```
    var myNotificationID = null;
    var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: "Restock",
        message: "Tee Black",
        iconUrl: "/images/Hp_Beta7.png",
        buttons: [
            {title: "small", iconUrl: "/images/..."},
            {title: "medium", iconUrl: "/images/..."}
        ]
    }
    chrome.notifications.create("", options, function(notificationId){
        myNotificationID = notificationId;
    });

    chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
        if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
            if (btnIdx === 0) {
                action1();
            } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
                action2();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: An optional parameter may be completely omitted even though it's a positional parameter, there's no need to specify an empty string.